# Circuits using KVL and Voltage Divison

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the image below, the top is the problem and the bottom circuit is my modified drawing. I'm unsure on where to start solving it. I used Ohm's Law to find $40$ V and then used Voltage Division to combine the three parallel resistors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfJqb.jpg

*The "$\dfrac {4000}{3}$" should be "$\dfrac {400}{3}$"*

I can use KVL to find: $-v + 40 + v_2 = 0$, but I am unsure on how to continue from there.

Comment: (1) Keep doing voltage drops around your loops. (2) Don't forget to relate the voltage drops to the split in current. (3) That should be $\frac{20}{3}$ not $\frac{4000}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

You combined three parallel $20 \Omega$ resistors, which should give $\dfrac {20}{3} \Omega $, not $\dfrac {400}{3} \Omega$. Your next step is to convert the leg $i$ through $20 \Omega$ into a voltage with a parallel resistance, which you can combine in parallel with the $\dfrac {20}{3} \Omega$.

Comment: Ok. I combined the $\dfrac{20}{3} \Omega$ resistor with the $20 \Omega$ resistor to get a $5 Ω$. Using KVL, I got −v + 40  V + V25Ω = 0.  I can do KVL again around the larger loop to get -v + 40 V + V20Ω + V5Ω = 0.  From there I still have four unknowns.

Comment: No, the $\frac {20}3 \Omega$ is not in parallel with the $20 \Omega$.  You have shown the $5-20-25$ node is $40 V$ above the bottom node.  Now find the voltage of the $20-10-\frac {20}3$ node relative to the bottom (in terms of $i$).  That will give you the current through the $20 V$.  Then you can get the current through the $\frac {20}3 V$.  Not an easy one.